# How to retrieve the KeyManager, TrustManager, and SecureRandom object being used by the SSL Client?

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, sslsocketfactory

I'm trying to create an SSL Socket factory that performs the handshake w/ the TSLv1.2 protocol.

What I have so far **[UPDATED 1/18]**:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
ServerSocketFactory sf = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
KeyManager[] km = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()).getKeyManagers();
TrustManager[] tm = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()).getTrustManagers();
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
sslContext.init(km, tm, random);
requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

I was hoping to grab the KeyManager, TrustManager, and SecureRandom objects from `SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()`, but there are no getters for this.
Is ther another place I could pull this from? or a more efficient way to do this?

I don't want to create the Key and Trust managers manually to avoid the need for system specific configurations.

Full Method for reference:

```
    public MyOutBoundClientWSImpl(URL wsdlUrl){
        super(wsdlUrl, serviceName);
        this.wsUrl=wsdlUrl;
        this.mService = this.getMySoapHttpPort();
        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)mService).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, REQUEST_TIMEOUT); // Timeout in millis
        requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, CONNECT_TIMEOUT); // Timeout in millis
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            ServerSocketFactory sf = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            KeyManager[] km = ??;
            TrustManager[] tm = ??;
            SecureRandom random = ??;
            sslContext.init(km, tm, random);
            requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creating them manually doesn't make your code system-specific. Unclear what your problem is.

Comment: I want to use whatever is being used by default. Also, I don't know the keystore password and am unsure if i can get it. Additionally, if i used a password or had different keystores in two different environments, i would need different configurations to set it up. This is what I meant by system specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check official documentation :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html

```
public final void init(KeyManager[] km,
        TrustManager[] tm,
        SecureRandom random)
                throws KeyManagementException
```

> Initializes this context. Either of the first two parameters may be
>   null in which case the installed security providers will be searched
>   for the highest priority implementation of the appropriate factory.
>   Likewise, the secure random parameter may be null in which case the
>   default implementation will be used.

Turns out this was very easy to do, you just have to pass all nulls to the init method.

```
    public MyOutBoundClientWSImpl(URL wsdlUrl){
        super(wsdlUrl, serviceName);
        this.wsUrl=wsdlUrl;
        this.mService = this.getMySoapHttpPort();
        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)mService).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, REQUEST_TIMEOUT); // Timeout in millis
        requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, CONNECT_TIMEOUT); // Timeout in millis
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            KeyManager[] km = null;
            TrustManager[] tm = null;
            SecureRandom random = null;                
            sslContext.init(km, tm, random);
            requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```